# List levels have no logical format in slidemaster in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a problem in a powerpoint template I am using from my company. The list level in the Slidemaster theme slide looks like this:

[image: e]

I would like for the third and fourth levels to occur underneath and to the right of the second level. I have tried all sorts of possible solutions but have no idea how to fix this. How do I get this to look like a normal bulleted list with a logical visual structure?

**Things I have tried**

- deleting and inserting a new slide master "Text" placeholder
- tabbing the third level in and out

Comment: You should list what you have already tried so that others may know what they should not suggest.

Comment: Done... please take a look at the original question...

Comment: On the Home tab, then Paragraph, try to increase the indent of the 3rd and 4th levels.

Comment: As I indicated in the original question I have already tried indenting the 3rd and 4th levels in and out using the "Increase List Level" buttons. This only applies the subsequent displayed list level. For instance if I do this to the third level it will make it bold and a bigger font, like the third level. If I do this to the second level, it will make it look like the third level. So this is a more fundamental problem...

Comment: You need to post the template itself, and are you allowed to modify it?

Comment: The template belongs to my company so I can't post it on here. I don't think I'm risking any serious jailtime by modifying the way the bullets look on the template.

Comment: Make sure that the ruler is shown, then try moving the first line and/or the left indents **manually** by moving them to the right

Comment: This is actually a fairly common font list pattern, first two levels bullets and continue on with body copy and subheads. You can have upto 9 levels controlled from your parent master slide, of different sizes, styles and colours. Are you having trouble creating the styles or understanding how it works or how it cascades through the template? Ask if you are having problems, happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the indent level on the master/layout by using the Tab key or the indent level button on the ribbon isn't what you need to do. Instead, use the ruler at the top of the slide. If you don't see it, rightclick anywhere off the slide and put a check next to Ruler.

Then click in any line of text that you want to adjust. Two little gadgets will appear on the ruler, one above, one below.

The upper one adjusts the indent distance from the left of the text box to the bullet.  The lower one adjusts the indent from the bullet to the text.

You can have up to 9 lines of text in the text/content placeholder; each can have its own formatting and indent levels.